# Bazel: How to run a WORKSPACE rule?

Tags: bazel

I have created a custom repository_rule to fetch a file from a samba share. I have a WORKSPACE file which uses this rule:

```
load('//build_tools/rules:download.bzl', 'smbget')

smbget(
   name="boost_test",
   path="/tools/boost/v1.61/lnx_x64/lib/libboost_atomic.so"
)
```

Now, I just want to run the rule to check it works? 
If I run `bazel build :boost_test` it complains about no such package. What do I need to do to be able to just run that rule?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the repository rule is implemented, but the `name` of a repository rule is not a target name (`:boost_test`), it's the repository name. In this case, it will look something like `@boost_test//:some_target`

It looks like the `smbget` implementation takes in a filepath to be exposed as a target. In the `repository_rule` implementation, you'll need to write a `BUILD` file, perhaps using [`repository_ctx.file`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html), that defines a default target name that you can refer to in the `@boost_test` repository.

For example, look at the [`http_file` documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#http_file). In the implementation of `http_file`, it downloads a file and creates a default BUILD file with a target called `file`, so you can refer to the downloaded file as `@some_name//:file` if you have a WORKSPACE rule like `http_file(name = "some_file", url = ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run the "smbget" rule (and not any of the rules that in may generate) you can use the fetch command:

`bazel fetch @boost_test//...`